# AC-DC Adapter - Output lower than rating and what's this 'cont' output for?

Tags: voltage, adapter, ac-dc

I have a Canon AC adapter, Model K30321, that I'd like to use in a project. I'm attempting to test the adapter for correct voltage output.

**Adapter specs:**

```
Input Voltage: 100 - 240VAC ~ 50/60Hz 60VA 0.65A
Output: 24V === 1A
Connector: 3 pin rectangle white flat 1 [ ■ ■ ■ ] 3
(from Left to right)
Pin1 = + 24v
Pin2 = Cont
Pin3 = GND
```

When I connect my multimeter to pin 1 and pin3, I see only about 8V DC.
I also see the same voltage between pin 2 and pin 3.

After some experimentation, I've learned that applying a constant 3.3V DC to the control pin causes the pin 1 voltage to rise and fall periodically between ~19V DC and ~21V DC. I can also hear a clicking sound coming from the adapter when doing this.

Questions:
I'm wondering if the control pin needs a PWM applied to it to function, or maybe it's expecting something else?

Thanks for all the advice!

Comment: You should have a load on the output to accurately measure that voltage. You should add to your question whether you believe the AC adapter is questionable because the equipment you are powering is not working, or you are just trying to determine if the adapter you have is OK.

Comment: You need resistor betwen cont and +

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a control input to put the adapter into standby mode so the printer uses less total power when in standby.

You might be able to coerce the adapter into giving you 24V by grounding the CONT line (use a few K resistor in series, just in case).

Comment: Grounding the CONT pin didn't change the voltage output on pin 1. Just curious, what bad things could happen that the few K resistor might prevent?

Comment: I'm thinking about putting 3.3V DC on the cont pin.. any reason why this could be a bad idea?

Comment: So, I went ahead and did this. After applying a constant 3.3V DC to the control pin I detect a rise in the voltage, but it's not constant, and still below the expected 24V. Also, I can hear a soft clicking sound coming from the adapter. Is it possible that I need to send some PWM to the control pin to keep it on all the time? I'm starting to think this is more trouble than it's worth!

Answer (score 0):

You need connect PIN1 (24V) and PIN2 (CONT), there is a MOSFET that enables voltage regulation, and as a result PIN1 will be 24V