# How do I get an output of 24V from a K30319 adapter?

Tags: voltage, output, adapter

The K30319 adapter is a 24V adapter made by Canon in Vietnam. I pulled it out of a Canon printer someone chucked in the garbage. The adapter works as far as I can tell. I'd like to use this adapter to build a 24V DC power supply if it's possible. There are three output pins. According to a vendor, and from left to right, pin 1 is +24V, pin 2 is GND, and pin 3 is Cont (control pin?). When measuring the adapter's output voltage with my multimeter I get a reading between 8 and 8.5V, and nowhere near the 24V printed on the adapter casing. I tried several connection combinations with my probes, but nothing I do gives me the stated 24V output voltage. Someone suggested I short the Cont pin to the +24V pin with series resistors. A 1k resistor apparently brings the voltage up to +24V. I've yet to try this, but I'm hesitant, because I may not find another free one so easily.

Comment: What's a K30319 adaptor? Please [edit] to include a link to the datasheet your working from and, even better, include a screengrab of the relevant part in your question. You can also hyperlink to the other question if it will help. (Just paste the URL. SE will tidy it up.) Welcome to EE.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two threads that discuss this type of power adapter,

[AC-DC Adapter - Output lower than rating and what's this 'cont' output for?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169639/ac-dc-adapter-output-lower-than-rating-and-whats-this-cont-output-for)

https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/canon-acdc-transformer-with-24v-cont-gnd-cont/

They both come to the same conclusion, that the Cont pin should be pulled up to the 24V pin and the voltage will then increase to that level.

**You would need to open this adapter up or have a proper manual/schematic to know if this was actually the correct thing to do. So no guarentees here, do at your own risk.**

Comment: Thanks jmb2341. I've already taken it apart. I will proceed with caution when I attempt to do this. First, I will read the discussions you've given me.